# Problems with Paypal and Magento 2 (Migrated from magento 1 with paypal working)

Tags: paypal, magento2

I'm having some problems with Paypal express in magento 2, I've migrated from magento 1, and now all is working, expect for paypal express.
I've debug paypal express and I get what I will post, for what I see the problem is maybe because o the prodcut prices are with tax included.
I've already acomplished to have the price without tax in checkout, but he always get the price with tax, what can I do? I've already disabled "Transfer cart line items".

The log is:

```
'AMT' => '16.70',
'CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
'INVNUM' => '1000012787',
'SHIPPINGAMT' => '3.75',
'ITEMAMT' => '12.95',
'TAXAMT' => '2.42',
'BUSINESS' => 'rtr',
'NOTETEXT' => NULL,
'EMAIL' => 'info@test.pt',
'FIRSTNAME' => 'ertr',
'LASTNAME' => 'trt',
'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
'SALUTATION' => NULL,
'SUFFIX' => NULL,
'COUNTRYCODE' => 'PT',
'STATE' => 'PR',
'CITY' => 'rt',
'STREET' => 'tr',
'ZIP' => '2335',
'PHONENUM' => 'rtrtrt',
'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'PT',
'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'PR',
'SHIPTOCITY' => 'rt',
'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'tr',
'SHIPTOZIP' => '2335',
'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => 'rtrtrt',
'SHIPTOSTREET2' => 'trt',
'STREET2' => 'trt',
'SHIPTONAME' => 'ertr trt',
'ADDROVERRIDE' => 1,
'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
'VERSION' => '72.0',
'USER' => '****',
'PWD' => '****',
'SIGNATURE' => '****',
'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-09-03T11:20:28Z',
'CORRELATIONID' => '403c3d4df0570',
'ACK' => 'Failure',
'VERSION' => '72.0',
'BUILD' => '53481737',
'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10413',
'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.',
'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.',
'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
```

Can anyone help me?

Best regards,
Leonel Nunes

Comment: Hello, there's nobody how had this problem and solve it?

Comment: I solved the problem, since the AMT item was already with tax, removing the tax_amt solved the problem